# golang sorting slice of IP addresses as strings

Tags: sorting, go

I'm looking to sort a slice of IP addresses (only IPV4) in Golang.

Using the native `sort` package using `sort.Strings()` doesn't work for obvious reasons since naturally `192.168.4.41` would be sorted in front of `192.168.4.5`

By sorting the numerical value of an IP alongside the IP string in a map I came up with a way to achieve it, but it feels too manual. Is this the most efficient way to break up the IP string and sort the addresses?

https://play.golang.org/p/FUYQKuhgUq8

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strconv"
  "strings"
  "sort"
)

func main() {
  ips := []string{
    "192.168.1.5",
    "69.52.220.44",
    "10.152.16.23",
    "192.168.3.10",
    "192.168.1.4",
    "192.168.1.41",
    }

ipsWithInt := make(map[string]int64)

for _, ip := range ips {
    ipStr := strings.Split(ip, ".")

    oct0, _ := strconv.ParseInt(ipStr[0], 10, 64)
    ipInt0 := oct0 * 255 * 255 * 255

    oct1, _ := strconv.ParseInt(ipStr[1], 10, 64)
    ipInt1 := oct1 * 255 * 255

    oct2, _ := strconv.ParseInt(ipStr[2], 10, 64)
    ipInt2 := oct2 * 255

    oct3, _ := strconv.ParseInt(ipStr[3], 10, 64)
    ipInt3 := oct3

    ipInt := ipInt0 + ipInt1 + ipInt2 + ipInt3

    ipsWithInt[ip] = ipInt
  }


  type kv struct {
    Key   string
    Value int64
  }

  var ss []kv
  for k, v := range ipsWithInt {
    ss = append(ss, kv{k, v})
  }

  sort.Slice(ss, func(i, j int) bool {
    return ss[i].Value < ss[j].Value
  })


  for _, kv := range ss {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", kv.Key)
  }
}
```

Results:

```
10.152.16.23
69.52.220.44
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.41
192.168.3.10
```

Comment: If this is working code, it would be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks  @JRLambert. I'm embarrassed to say I didn't think of that, I will keep it in mind for future.

Comment: Note that the quoted code will sort 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.0.255, for example, as if they are equal. It should multiply by 256, not 255 (really, it should left-shift 1 byte). But, see my answer for an easier-to-read approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are lots of possible ways to do it, but the easiest that comes quickly to mind would be to parse them into `net.IP`s (which are just byte slices, a more accurate representation of an IP), and then sort those:

```
realIPs := make([]net.IP, 0, len(ips))

for _, ip := range ips {
    realIPs = append(realIPs, net.ParseIP(ip))
}

sort.Slice(realIPs, func(i, j int) bool {
    return bytes.Compare(realIPs[i], realIPs[j]) < 0
})
```

Working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/UtuvVz44_c8

This has the added advantage of working equally well with IPv6 addresses with no modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to sort IP strings, and my lists were relatively short so a little extra work per comparison was okay since there is no up front work required and no conversion back to strings necessary at the end. Not better than the answer from a few years ago, but different.

```golang
func sortIPs(ips []string) {
    sort.Slice(ips, func(i, j int) bool {
        a := ips[i]
        b := ips[j]
        ais4 := strings.Contains(a, ".")
        bis4 := strings.Contains(b, ".")
        // If not the same IP version, put IPv4 ahead of IPv6.
        if ais4 != bis4 {
            return ais4
        }
        sep := byte('.')
        if !ais4 {
            sep = byte(':')
        }
        for {
            if a == b {
                break
            }
            ahead, atail := a, ""
            bhead, btail := b, ""
            if i := strings.IndexByte(a, sep); i != -1 {
                ahead, atail = a[:i], a[i+1:]
            }
            if i := strings.IndexByte(b, sep); i != -1 {
                bhead, btail = b[:i], b[i+1:]
            }
            if ahead == bhead {
                a = atail
                b = btail
                continue
            }
            // shorter comes first
            if len(ahead) != len(bhead) {
                return len(ahead) < len(bhead)
            }
            return ahead < bhead
        }

        return true
    })
}
```

Comment: This will work only with non-compressed IPv6 textual addresses, that is, it will fail for `fe80::1`, if I'm reading the code correctly.

Comment: @TheDiveO Probably right. It doesn't look like it would cause a panic and it looks like it would provide a consistent ordering, but it doesn't treat missing zero fields as a reason to order such an address earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do this with a few lines of polymorphic code that works with both IPv4 and IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Using the slice "ips" from your code:

```golang
ipAddrs := make([]*ipaddr.IPAddress, 0, len(ips))
for _, str := range ips {
    ipAddrs = append(ipAddrs, ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(str).GetAddress())
}
sort.Slice(ipAddrs, func(i, j int) bool {
    return ipAddrs[i].Compare(ipAddrs[j]) < 0
})
fmt.Println("sorted:", ipAddrs)
```

Output:

```
sorted: [10.152.16.23 69.52.220.44 192.168.1.4 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.41 192.168.3.10]
```